# How to order a query in Ecto using a JSONB field with a DB Postgres?

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

How coud we order a query in Ecto (Elixir Phoenix framework) using the JSONB field.

I need to do something like:

ORDER BY data->>'cercle_rating' DESC

I know i can't use fragment in order_by: method.

What should i do ?

Thank you !!

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can do

order_by: fragment("data->>'cercle_rating' DESC ")

It is working fine !